Creating an ad creative with multiple asset placements, titles and primary texts with the Meta Marketing API
I want to create an ad creative with the Meta/Facebook Marketing API. The goal is to create an ad creative which I can turn into an ad which has multiple images and primary texts and titles.
As shown in the picture, I want to have the same image in "Feeds, In-Stream Ads for Videos and Reels, Search Results" and "Right Hand, Search Results". I want a different image in "Stories and Reels, Apps and Websites".
Additionally, I want to specify multiple primary texts and multiple titles.
I tried to create the creative using this:
{
    "object_story_spec": {
      "page_id": "PAGE_ID"
    },
    "asset_feed_spec": {
      "images": [
        {
          "hash": "HASH1",
          "adlabels": [{"name": "label_feed"}]
        },
        {
          "hash": "HASH2",
          "adlabels": [{"name": "label_story"}]
        }
      ],
      "bodies": [
        {
          "text": "Begin Your Adventure"
        }
      ],
      "titles": [
        {
          "text": "Level Up"
        },
        {
          "text": "Level Up 2"
        }
      ],
      "call_to_action_types": [
        "SHOP_NOW"
      ],
      "link_urls": [
        {
          "website_url": "https://www.example.com/"
        }
      ],
      "ad_formats": [
        "SINGLE_IMAGE"
      ],
      "asset_customization_rules": [
        {
          "customization_spec": {
            "publisher_platforms": [
              "facebook"
            ],
            "facebook_positions": [
              "feed"
            ]
          },
          "image_label": {
            "name": "label_feed"
          }
        },
        {
          "customization_spec": {
            "publisher_platforms": [
              "instagram"
            ],
            "instagram_positions": [
              "story"
            ]
          },
          "image_label": {
            "name": "label_story"
          }
        }
      ]
   
  },
  "status": "PAUSED",
  "degrees_of_freedom_spec": {
        "creative_features_spec": {
            "standard_enhancements": {
                "enroll_status": "OPT_OUT"
            }
        }
    }
}

However, it gives me an error:
Multiple title elements cannot be applied to rule #1 (Priority, if specified, or index of the rule) in the Ad Asset Feed.
Additionally, it seems like I have to specify adlabels in the asset story spec. How can I place the images in the categories without the adlabels?
